# How to make Highcharts legends focus on the chart that it belongs to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two charts on the page and both charts have the same legends. Clicking the legend entries in the second chart seems to affect the first chart. How can I focus so that the legend strictly focus on the chart it belongs to?

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/8xu21dpz/

first chart data:

```
series: [{
    name: 'info 1',
    data: [1.615478304, 29.99195083]
},{
    name: 'info 2',
    data: [3.279163489, 43.97775501]
},{
    name: 'info 3',
    data: [19.27465688, 9.135811503]
}]
```

second chart data:

```
data = [
    [{
        name: 'info 1'
        data: gen_data([1, 3, 13, 250, 450, 750], 26541.0),
        color: colors[0]
    },{
        name: 'info 2'
        data: gen_data([2, 4, 23, 250, 550, 1141, 1500], 53874),
        color: colors[1]
    }],
    [{
        name: 'info 3'
        data: gen_data([13, 40, 300, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000], 316667),
        color: colors[2]
    }],
]



function set_legend() {
    legend = $('#legend');
    legend.html('');
    let listed = {};
    $.each(Highcharts.charts, function(i, chrt) {
        $.each(chrt.series, function(j, serie) {
            let tmp_key = serie.name.replace(/[\s,-]/g, '');
            if (!Object.keys(listed).includes(tmp_key)) {
                legend.append(
                    '<div class="item '+tmp_key+'"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:' +
                    serie.color +
                    '"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' +
                    serie.name +
                    '</div></div>'
                );
                listed[tmp_key] = [serie];
            } else {
                listed[tmp_key].push(serie);
            }
        });
    });

    Object.keys(listed).forEach(key => {
        // Get the legend and add a click handler
        $('#legend .'+key).click(function() {
            listed[key].forEach(serie => {
                if (serie.visible) serie.setVisible(false);
                else serie.setVisible(true);
            });
        });
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your series to the legend the HighCharts way (using the legend property of the series object)?  Right now you are just adding some html elements to the html container that highcharts uses to display legends, but the internal workings of which legend goes with which chart won't work like that.

Comment: @James thanks for the response. I do have the legend object available in the code. Here's the JSFiddle for complete example if you can please review and let me how to fix the issue https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/8xu21dpz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some flag to avoid looping through the first chart.

```
  $.each(Highcharts.charts, function(i, chrt) {
    //
    // Flag to avoid looping through the first chart
    //
    if (i !== 0) {
      $.each(chrt.series, function(j, serie) {
        let tmp_key = serie.name.replace(/[\s,-]/g, '');
        if (!Object.keys(listed).includes(tmp_key)) {
          legend.append(
            '<div class="item ' + tmp_key + '"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:' +
            serie.color +
            '"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' +
            serie.name +
            '</div></div>'
          );
          listed[tmp_key] = [serie];
        } else {
          listed[tmp_key].push(serie);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yatz5m38/

Answer (score 0):

A JSFiddle would be nice. Do notice though that

```
            if (serie.visible) serie.setVisible(false);
            else serie.setVisible(true);
```

can be simplified to `serie.setVisible(!serie.visible)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here's the JSFiddle if you can please take a look and let me know the issue https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/8xu21dpz/